# Cleanup redirected output file from failed command

Tags: scripting, cron, pipe, io-redirection

When doing:

```
CMD > file.out
```

if CMD fails (non-zero exit code), 'file.out' with be empty or incomplete.

I looking for a way to cleanup in case the CMD fails.

When CMD is run in a CRON job I would prefer for the directed output file to be deleted instead of leaving an empty/incomplete file behind.

My initial idea was:

```
if ! CMD > file.out; then rm file.out; fi
```

However it hides the CMD exit status, making it unsuitable. (especially for CRON)

- Can anyone think a better solution ?
- Is there some functionality in bash or sh that would allow this ?
- I was hoping maybe there is some 'tee' like utility that could:

  - It would redirect STDOUT output to a file
  - If the command fails it would remove output file
  - In all case it would return the CMD exit code

Comment: I ended up doing a small script that calls CMD and that create a temporary file and then move it on success. It also has additional logic that was needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial idea is good and could be expanded into

```
if ! CMD >file.out; then rm file.out; exit 1; fi
```

If you need to capture the specific exit status from `CMD`, then do that and `exit` with it later:

```
if ! CMD >file.out; then err="$?"; rm file.out; exit "$err"; fi
```

Note that you can't use `exit "$?"` since at that point, `rm` has modified `$?`.

---

`tee` will always create its output file, no matter if data is available to put into it, so you would have the same issue as you had from the start.

Comment: Thx for the input. Indeed that would work.

I understand ```tee``` will always act this way. Just thought it could be nice to have another cmd that does exactly this... but it might be better to just use standard unix tool / rely on bash.